# Find the limit of sequence if it is converges

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits

Find the limit if it is converges. 
The following question ask whether the sequence is converges or diverges.

From the look of it, i can see that it is converges because the sequence value is getting smaller and smaller, however i need to find the general term first an = ??? in order to find the limit, which i am stuck. Please advice thank you.

[View image here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7y1Ku.png)

Comment: Calculator value obtain 2 if i sub the value inside the calculator. But how to proof it.

Comment: If you want to find a general pattern to the sequence, I think it's easiest to note that every term can easily be written as a power of $4$. Then you can focus on how the exponent changes from term to term, which is a bit more manageable.

Comment: Hint: $t_{n+1}=\sqrt[3]{4t_{n}}$ so if there is a limit $t$ then $t=\sqrt[3]{4t}$

Comment: Note that drhab's method works because the map $x\mapsto (4x)^{\frac{1}{3}}$ is continuous.

Comment: You should typeset the problem properly. Your image URL may not work in the future.